# TOAD Formatting - Alignment

Tags: plsql, code-formatting, toad

I need my code block to look like this -

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE 
  /* *******************
  * my comment block
  * *******************/ 
  my_package AS
```

However, when I hit use format code option in TOAD, the formatted output I get looks like this -

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE /* *******************
                            * my comment block
                            * *******************/ 
  my_package AS
```

I couldn't find the option specific to this particular formatting setting in View->Formatting Options. Can anyone point out the setting that lets me keep my comment block aligned to left?
[I am using TOAD for Oracle 10.6.1.3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug!  Please report it to them or at least add your example to that post on Toad World.  I have found bugs and they were real quick to jump on them.

http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/toad_for_oracle_beta_program/f/86/t/24464.aspx